# InvalidOperationException during row validated event

Tags: c#, invalidoperationexception

I have 2 DataGridViews bound to BindingDataSources which hold DataTables from a database wrapper class which uses a SqlDatabaseAdapter to manage the data.

I am trying to allow the user to add/edit rows and then have the changes be immediately committed to the database without clicking a save button.  I used the RowValidated event to write back to SQL, but I found that if I changed the same row twice in a single session I would get a concurrency error.  To fix this I refreshed the DataSource after each update.

This works for one table, but not for the second.  In researching this I found that the exception is the CORRECT behavior.  So the question is 2 fold.
1.   Why is it working at all?
2.   What is the correct way to accomplish this goal?

Relevant Code:

```
private void RefreshWebDisplay()
{
    webDisplay = new WebDisplay(_configString);

    BindingSource bsDisplay = new BindingSource();
    bsDisplay.DataSource = webDisplay.Display;
    dgvWebDisplay.DataSource = bsDisplay;  //This line does NOT throw an exception
    dgvWebDisplay.Refresh();

    BindingSource bsPages = new BindingSource();
    bsPages.DataSource = webDisplay.Pages;
    dgvWebPages.DataSource = bsPages;  //This line throws an InvalidOperationException
    dgvWebPages.Refresh();
}

//I combined the RowValidated event functions for testing, trying to eliminate all differences. 
private void dgvWebDGV_RowValidated(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridView dgv = sender as DataGridView;
    if (dgv.NewRowIndex != e.RowIndex)
    {
        (dgv.DataSource as BindingSource).EndEdit();

        if (((dgv.DataSource as BindingSource).DataSource as DataTable).GetChanges() != null)
        {                
            if (dgv == dgvWebDisplay)                    
                webDisplay.Display = (dgv.DataSource as BindingSource).DataSource as DataTable;
            else if (dgv == dgvWebPages) 
                webDisplay.Pages = (dgv.DataSource as BindingSource).DataSource as DataTable;                      

             RefreshWebDisplay();
        }
    }
}

class WebDisplay
{
    ...
    public DataTable Display
    {
        get
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            DisplayAdapter.Fill(dt);
            return dt;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != null)
                DisplayAdapter.Update(value);

        }
    }
    public DataTable Pages
    {
        get
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            PageAdapter.Fill(dt);
            return dt;
        }
        set
        {
            if(value != null)
                PageAdapter.Update(value);
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While doing a line by line comparison of both DataGridViews I found that I set AutoGenerateColumns to false on the one that had the desired behavior, after doing the same to the second DataGridView, it also behaved correctly.